# Is discussing a specific occurrence of a previous sin a chillul hashem if it’s known you’ve done the sin before?

Tags: chilul-kidush-hashem

The [Kesef Mishneh on Hilchos Teshuva 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.2.5?lang=bi&p2=Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.2.5.2&lang2=bi) says that revealing a previously committed sin to someone who doesn’t know you’ve sinned is a chillul hashem. If that person knows you’ve done the sin before and you tell him a specific occurrence, is that also chillul hashem?

Example: someone who is known to have watched “rated R” films saying that they saw a specific film, or someone who is known to have eaten treif discussing a specific restaurant etc.

Comment: Follow your heart - will it make the people / the world better?

Comment: If it's not in a good purpose, it's perhaps as you speak about this without shame, a kind of effrontery

Comment: Something else to consider that People tend to forget - Lashon Hara applies to oneself as well & sharing experiences of previous sins definitely sounds like it's Lashon Hara

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's a Chilul Hashem is that it's Chutzpa to *brag* (or even mention) that one went against Hashem's will.

It seems to me that going into specific details about a sin is similar to *bragging*; one should be so embarrassed about the sin that one doesn't want to discuss it in any detail.